# Disable web app auto-reloading in standalone Jetty server

Tags: java, web-applications, jetty

How can I disable .war auto-reloading in Jetty server?

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9758983/maven-jetty-do-not-reload-the-whole-application-when-modifying-only-static-fil) question addresses the problem, but its for Jetty Maven, while I am using standalone version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look for the scanInterval in the WebAppProvider configuration and set it to 0 to disable hot deployment.

http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/hot-deployment.html